# Not hiding google map markers on javascript application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, cordova

I'm developing the mobile app on phonegap with using google maps. I need to hide markers and labels from map.

After the checking on PC everything works good, but on phone labels are disappear and markers are leaving until the render of that square where the marker was.

```
var options = {
    labelContent: equipmentModel.get("name"),
    labelVisible: true,
    title: equipmentModel.get("name"),
    map: MLocateApp.ModuleMap.Map.googleMap,
    icon: equipmentModel.getImage()
};
```

and hiding next code 
`setVisible(isVisible)`

Comment: So, you're having this problem. Please show us your code, otherwise, we won't be able to help you fix the problem.

Comment: `var options = {
            labelContent: equipmentModel.get("name"),
            labelVisible: true,
            title: equipmentModel.get("name"),
            map: MLocateApp.ModuleMap.Map.googleMap,
            icon: equipmentModel.getImage()
        };`

Comment: ... In your question, not in comments.

Comment: Sorry, question fixed.